# 'Insert Into' Access 2010 from java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2010, insert-into

I am using Access 2010 and java 6, I am trying to execute this query but it is giving me an error, here is my code:

```
String sql = "insert into accounts (title , date , amount) values ('titlexx' , '21-01-2014' , 26000) ";
getConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement
```

I don't know where I am going wrong guys.

Comment: what is the datatype of date column?

Comment: Put the semicolon `;` inside the statement string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=286335) page, `date` is a MS-Access keyword. Reformulating your query to something like so should do the trick:

```
String sql = "insert into accounts (title , [date] , amount) values ('titlexx' , '21-01-2014' , 26000) ";
```

Comment: @Shahe: It might be a good idea to wrap your column names in square braces just in case in the future, it can save quite some hassle.

Comment: Yeah you're right buddy, thanks for the heads up, I will consider it

Answer (score 0):

String sql = "insert into accounts (title , date , amount) values (' "+"titlexx"+" ' , ' "+"21-01-2014"+" ' , 26000) ";
--if title and date are string.